# how to intent and toast from myItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, android-intent, toast, itemizedoverlay

i have mapview with custom itemizedoverlay. i put two button at info window. my question is my code at neural button right? i put intent and toast but it didnt show. here is my code. thnx.

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Drawable marker;
private Context mContext;

Route route;
MapView mapView;
private ArrayList<Lokasi> list_fasilitas = new ArrayList<Lokasi>();

public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(defaultMarker);
     items = new ArrayList(); //mbuh
    marker = defaultMarker;
}

public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
    return (OverlayItem) items.get(index);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return items.size();

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see
 * com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay#draw(android.graphics.Canvas,
 * com.google.android.maps.MapView, boolean)
 */
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    // boundCenterBottom(marker);

}

public void addItem(OverlayItem item) {
    items.add(item);
    populate();
}

//@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = items.get(0);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());

    dialog.setNeutralButton("location", new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {



            for (int i = 0; i < list_fasilitas.size(); i++) {


                try
                {
                     String nama = list_fasilitas.get(i).nama_rs;
                     Toast.makeText(mContext, "lala:"+nama, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     initializeData(nama);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, detailactivity.class);
                     mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                 } 

            }



        }

        });


    dialog.setPositiveButton("Close", new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            arg0.dismiss();
        }

    });


    dialog.show();
    return true;
}

private void initializeData(String namars) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namars",namars));
         sendData(nameValuePairs);
}

 private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
     try
     {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.199.1/RS/generate_detailrs.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
     } 
 }
```

}

here is my neural button code :

```
dialog.setNeutralButton("location", new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {



            for (int i = 0; i < list_fasilitas.size(); i++) {


                try
                {
                     String nama = list_fasilitas.get(i).nama_rs;
                     Toast.makeText(mContext, "lala:"+nama, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     initializeData(nama);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, detailactivity.class);
                     mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
                 } 

            }

        }

        });
```

Comment: R u passing the activity context to your overlay class from your activity class?

Comment: Anything useful in the logcat?